Calling functions on array make the program to exit
I want a Game of Life program in the console.
The parameters to initialize the 'field' can be changed in the mainMenu(). When all is done, it returns 1, and the drawing begins.
When we return from draw, we get back to mainMenu(). This happens for ever in an infinite while loop. All functions work when tested separately. Problematic ones are border(), init(), etc.
What am I missing? I'm a beginner in C.
(fileIn() doesn't work proper, but that's not the issue here.)
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <conio.h>

//structure for storing the state of each cell
typedef struct Cell{
    bool state, nState;
}Cell;

char path[50];
int rule;

Cell** setup(int width, int height){
    //create field
    int size = (width+2)*(height+2);
    Cell** field = malloc(size * sizeof(Cell));;
    
    if (field == NULL){
        printf("Malloc Error!");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return field;
}

void clrscr(){
    printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
}

void welcome(){
    clrscr();
    printf("This program was created by:\033[1;31m\n           U+0466.\033[1;m\n");
    sleep(2);
}

void display(Cell* c, int width, int height){
    clrscr();
    int size = (width+2)*(height+2);
    printf("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <(width*2-32)/2; i++)
        printf(" ");
    printf("\033[1;31mThe Game of Life on a %dx%d grid.\033[1;m", width, height);

    //draw the field
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (i % (width+2) == 0)
            printf("\n");

        //skip border
        if (i < width+2){
            printf("X ");
            continue;}
        else if (i >= (size-(width+2))){
            printf("X ");
            continue;}
        else if ((i+1) % (width+2) == 0){
            printf("X ");
            continue;}
        else if ((i) % (width+2) == 0){
            printf("X ");
            continue;}
        
        (c[i].state)? printf("O ") : printf("  ");
    }
}

int fileIn(int* width, int *height){
    //get path from user
    printf("\033[1;31m");
    printf("Please enter file path: ");
    printf("\033[1;m");
    scanf("%s", path);
    
    //open file
    FILE *fptr = fopen(path, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL){
        return -1;
    }

    //find the dimenisons of the field
    char ch;
    int h = 0;
    int w = 0;
    int wmax = 0;

    for (ch = getc(fptr); ch != EOF; ch = getc(fptr)){
        //0 or 1
        if ((ch == 48)|(ch == 49)){
            w++;
        }
        //linebreak
        else if (ch == 10){
            if (w!=0)
                h++;
            if (w > wmax){
                wmax = w;
            }
            w = 0;
        }
    }
    if ((wmax > 0)|(height > 0)){
        *width = wmax;
        *height = h + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void fileOut(Cell* c, int width, int height){
    FILE *fptr = NULL;
    fptr = fopen("out.txt", "w+");

    //create a header
    for (int i = 1; i <= width; i++)
        fprintf(fptr, "-");
    fprintf(fptr, "\nThe Game of Life, by U+O466\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= width; i++)
        fprintf(fptr, "-");

    //write file
    int size = (width+2)*(height+2);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        //skip border
        if (i < width+2)
            continue;
        else if (i >= (size-(width+2)))
            continue;
        else if ((i+1) % (width+2) == 0)
            continue;
        else if ((i-3) % (width+2) == 0)
            continue;
        
        //write states
        else if (i % (width+2) == 0)
            fprintf(fptr, "\n");
        ((c+i)->state)? fprintf(fptr, "1"):fprintf(fptr, "0");
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}

void initFile(Cell* c, int w, int h){
    int size = (w+2)*(h+2);
    FILE* fptr = fopen(path, "r");

    char ch;

    //init to 0, than fill with data
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        (c+i)->state = 0;
    
    for (int j = 1; j < h+1; j++){
        for (int i = 1; i < w+1; i++){
            ch = getc(fptr);

            if (ch == 49){
                (c+j*(w+2)+i)->state = 1;
            }
            //linebreak - doesnt handle 'empty' rows properly
            else if ((ch == 10)){
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void initAuto(Cell* c, int width, int height){
    //populate first row with 0, set center as 1
    for (int i = 0; i < width+1; i++)
        (c+i)->state = 0;
    (width%2 == 0)? ((c+((width+1)/2))->state = 1) : ((c+(width/2))->state = 1);

    for (int j = 1; j < height+1; j++){
        for (int i = 1; i < width+1; i++){
            char pat = 0;
            //find out current pattern
            pat |= ((c+(j*(width+2))+i-1)->state << 2 );
            pat |= ((c+(j*(width+2))+i)->state << 1 );
            pat |= ((c+(j*(width+2))+i+1)->state);
            //set next rows state, based on the rule
            (c+((j+1)*(width+2))+i)->state = (rule >> pat) & 1;
        }
    }
}

void init(Cell* c, int w, int h, int mode){
    int size = (w+2)*(h+2);

    switch (mode){
        case 0:
        case 1:
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                (c+i)->state = mode;
            break;
        case 2:
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                (c+i)->state = rand()%2;
            break;
        case 3:
            initAuto(c, w, h);
            break;
        case 4:
            initFile(c, w, h);
            break;

    }
}

void border(Cell *c, int w, int h, int mode){
    w+=2;
    h+=2;
    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++){
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++){
            if ((i==0) | (i == w-1) | (j==0) | (j == h-1)){
                switch (mode){
                    case 0: //dead
                    case 1: //alive
                        (c+(w*j)+i)->state = mode;
                        break;
                    case 2: //tiling - corners not handled 
                        if (i==0)
                            (c+(w*j))->state = (c+(w*j)+i-1)->state;
                        else if (i == w-1)
                            (c+(w*j)+i)->state = (c+(w*j)+1)->state;
                        if (j==0)
                            (c+i)->state = (c+(w*(h-2))+i)->state;
                        else if (j == h-1)
                            (c+(w*(h-1))+i)->state = (c+w+i)->state;                       
                        break;
                
                }
            (c+(w*j)+i)->nState =  (c+(w*j)+i)->state;
            }
        }
    }
}

void update(Cell* c, int w, int h){
    w = w + 2;
    h = h + 2;
    int size = w*h;

    for (int j = 1; j < h - 1; j++){
        for (int i = 1; i < w + 1; i++){
            //reset counter, then count neighbors
            int nbors = 0;
            nbors +=(c+(j-1)*w+(i-1))->state + //up-left
                    (c+(j-1)*w+(i))  ->state + //up
                    (c+(j-1)*w+(i+1))->state + //up-right
                    (c+(j)  *w+(i-1))->state + //left
                    (c+(j)  *w+(i+1))->state + //right
                    (c+(j+1)*w+(i-1))->state + //down-left
                    (c+(j+1)*w+(i))  ->state + //down
                    (c+(j+1)*w+(i+1))->state;  //down-right
            //decide next state based on current (rule: B3/S23)
            if ((c+(j*w)+i)->state)
                (c+(j*w)+i)->nState = (nbors == 3 || nbors == 2);
            else if (nbors == 3)
                (c+(j*w)+i)->nState = 1;
            else
                (c+(j*w)+i)->nState = 0;
        }
    }
    //update all cells
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        (c+i)->state = (c+i)->nState;
}

int menu(char* opts[], char msg[]){
    system("cls");
    printf("\033[1;31m");
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    printf("\033[1;m");
    //print options
    printf("(0) Return\n");
    int i = 0;
    while (opts[i] != NULL){
        printf("(%d) %s\n", i+1, opts[i]);
        i++;
    }
    //get answer
    
    printf("\033[1;31mPlease choose an option! (0-%d):\033[1;m ", i);
    int choice;
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    //if answer is not an option, try again
    if (choice > i){
        menu(opts, msg);
    }
    return choice-1;
}

int draw(Cell* c, int width, int height, int borderM){
    char ch;
    bool playing = false;
    
    while(1){
        display(c, width, height);
        printf("\033[1;31m\n0:     Return\nTab:   Continue\nSpace: Play\nEsc:   Exit\033[1;m ");
    
        ch = getch();
        if (ch == 27)
            return -1;

        else if(ch == 9){
            update(c, width, height);
            border(c, width, height, borderM);
            continue;
        }
        else if (ch == 48){
            return 0;
        }
        else if (ch == 32){
            playing = true;
            while (playing){
                display(c, width, height);
                update(c, width, height);
                border(c, width, height, borderM);
                printf("\033[1;31m\nPress [Space] to stop!\033[1;m ");
                sleep(1); 
                
                if (kbhit()) {
                    ch = getch();
                    if (ch == 32)
                        playing = false;
                }
            }  
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int mainMenu(int* width, int* height, int* borderM, int* initM){
    //def menu options
    char* initOpts[] = {"Dead", "Alive", "Random", "Automaton", "File", NULL};
    char* borderOpts[] = {"Dead", "Alive", "Infinite", NULL};
    
    //print main menu
    clrscr();
    printf("\033[1;31mMage of File by U+0466\n\033[1;m");
    printf("(0) Exit\n");
    printf("(1) Size: %d x %d\n", *width, *height);
    if (*initM == 3) //automaton rule printing
        printf("(2) Starting state: %s (Rule %d)\n", initOpts[*initM], rule);
    else if (*initM == 4) //file path printing
        printf("(2) Starting state: %s\n", path);
    else
        printf("(2) Starting state: %s\n", initOpts[*initM]);
    printf("(3) Border mode: %s\n", borderOpts[*borderM]);
    printf("(4) Play\n");
    printf("\033[1;31mPlease choose an option! (0-4):\033[1;m ");

    //get answers
    int opt;
    scanf(" %d", &opt);
    int ans;

    //create submenus
    switch (opt){
        case 0: return -1;
        case 1: clrscr();
            printf("\033[1;31mEnter Width and Height:\033[1;m \n");
            scanf("%d %d", width, height);
            break;
        case 2:
            ans = menu(initOpts, "How do you want to populate the field?");
            if (ans == 3){
                clrscr();
                printf("\033[1;31mEnter rule for Cellular Automaton (0-255):\033[1;m ");
                scanf("%d", &rule);
                *initM = ans;
            }
            else if (ans == 4){
                clrscr();
                int tmp = fileIn(width, height);
                while (tmp == -1){
                    printf("\033[1;31mInvalid file, try again?\033[1;m (Y/N) ");
                    char ans;
                    scanf("%c", &ans);
                    if (ans == 89)
                        tmp = fileIn(width, height);
                    else if(ans == 78)
                        break;
                }
                if (tmp != -1)
                    *initM = 4;
                }
            else
                *initM = ans;
            break;
        case 3:
            ans = menu(borderOpts, "How do you want to set the border?");
            if (ans != -1)
                *borderM = ans;
            break;
        case 4:
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int width = 20, height = 30;
    int borderM = 1, initM = 2;

    Cell** field;
    field = NULL;
    int state = 0;
    
    //welcome();
    
    while (1){
        switch (state){
            case -1:
                free(field);
                printf("Good Bye!");
                return 0;
            case 0:
                state =  mainMenu(&width, &height, &borderM, &initM);
                if (state == 1){
                    free(field);
                    field =  setup(width, height);
                    init(*field, width, height, initM);
                    border(*field, width, height, borderM);
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                state = draw(*field, width, height, borderM);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


There is a lot of code there. Could you try and make a minimal example that demonstrates the problem, please? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Please try to create a [mre] to show us. With emphasis on the minimal part. Basically remove parts of your code until it works. Then add one line at a time back, until it stops working. From the knowledge you gain through that, create a new program which only does the thing causing the crash (and make sure it actually replicates it), and [edit] your question to show it.

And of course, learn how to use a debugger, which will help greatly when debugging your programs.

Well, looking at the very start of the code and this single line: Cell** field = malloc(size * sizeof(Cell));; - why does it have two semicolons? It seem to be allocating space for array  of Cell, but is assigning the result to Cell** instead of Cell*. This type confusion alone can cause all sorts of bugs.

Also, init(*field, ...)? Why do you dereference the pointer here? It's the same as field[0]. And at that point, ``field[0]doesn't actually point anywhere, so you pass an uninitialized pointer. I concur with @EugeneSh., you're using pointer-to-pointer in the wrong way. It should be onlyCell *, not Cell **`.

Aside: this printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J"); gives a warning from MSVC: 'e': unrecognized character escape sequence. Doesn't conio have a clrscr() function?

Thanks for the answers. What I'm trying to do is malloc space for a Cell array in the setup function. In my - previous? - understanding an array is characterized by a pointer to its first element. So I thought a pointer to an array is a pointer to a pointer, in my case Cell**. Is it?

In your setup function you use assign malloc(size * sizeof(Cell)) on a Cell** type, if you wanted to make an array of Cell pointers you should use sizeof(Cell*) or sizeof(*field).

thanks for all the fast answers!
what I THOUGHT im doing is to create a pointer to the start of a CELL array, how do i do that then?

If you just want a cell array you can change field to be a cell* and use malloc(size * sizeof(cell)) that will be a linear array: cell[0], cell[1] etc... If you want a matrix then you should keep the code as it is but change the malloc to cell* rather than cell, that will give you an array or pointers or a matrix since each pointer can be the start of an array like this: field[0] = cell[0], cell[1]...
